# STRMQM fails with AMQ7047

Tags: security, ibm-mq

We have migrated our MQ server from 7.1 to 7.5.
When we are trying to restore queue manager, we are getting a **STRMQM fails with AMQ7047** error. Some queue managers are running, but some are giving an error.

Comment: Is the error also giving a reason code?  What ID are you using to start the queue manager?  give details of how you performed the "migration" .

Comment: There was no reason code.used rood it to start queue manager.we are using HP-ux os with mq version 7.1.  We did server upgradation  from 7.1 to 7.5.before that I stopped all the queue managers. 

and took backup of  /var/mqm/ and /opt/mqm/ folders.Then I removed base version of mq that is 7.1 and installed new version of mq ie. 7.5.
after successful installation I tried to start all the queue managers.but some queue mamagers are started but some giving an error.Is there any other way to take backup of queue managers.

Comment: when I type strmqm QMname it gives  The STRMQM command fails with AMQ7047, An unexpected error was encountered by a command, after upgrading WebSphere MQ. 

Cause

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possibly due to an authority issue. 
Check the ID you are using and also the file permissions to be sure they are still owned by that ID. 
It may be a file permissions (or symbolic links) issue related to restoring MQ from file backup. 
The mqm ID should be used to start the queue manager.

Comment: can you please tell me which file require permission and how to check it. and how to restore MQ from file backup.I don't have much idea about mq

Comment: There was no reason code.we used root id to start queue manager

Comment: You should use the mqm ID (on UNIX)  to start the queue manager, not root.   Are you on UNIX or iseries?

Comment: yes,we have hp-ux os. I tried to start queue manager using mqm id but still getting same error "STRMQM command fails with AMQ7047, An unexpected error was encountered by a command"

Answer (score 0):

Normally "migrate" and "restore" do not go together.  Migrate means to stop all QMgrs, apply the new version of MQ, then restart the QMgrs, allowing MQ to automatically upgrade any file structures.  That both were done is a huge red flag and points to the possible root causes.

Restore might mean to take an object and ACL backup and apply it to a new, enpty QMgr.  This requires the QMgr to be running so cannot be the usage to which you refer.

Restore might also mean to take MQ file images from a prior point in time and restore them to a filesystem.  This sounds like what you have and probably the cause of the problem.

For example: `Upgrade --> Start MQ --> Stop MQ --> Restore backup` can fail because MQ thinks it had already upgraded the QMgr data files and finds the wrong formats.

Obviously: `Upgrade --> Start MQ --> Restore backup` will fail because it overlays files in use.

In general, any restore of the QMgr can fail if the backup of the files was taken while the QMgr was running and under load.  The backup job has to pass over the queue files and the log files and the latency assures that the two sets of files are inconsistent.  If there are deep queues, the inconsistency can occur between two adjacent queue files.  For this reason, point-in-time backups of MQ *must* be taken while the QMgr is stopped, but not many people actually do it that way.

If one of these scenarios does not explain the behavior you are seeing, I would suggest updating the question with very specific detail of what exactly was done and in what order.